# opening pop up window in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

Am running asp.net application with c#. I want to open a new pop up window on the button click either in c# or javascript..in the pop up window i have to do some operations..how to do that?Is there any articles to  know the basic concepts about these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Google search for 'javascript popup' or 'c# popup' would have given you lots of results.

Comment: There's no such thing as a popup in C#. asp.net runs in the server way before any page gets rendered on the client.

Comment: [check this](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4505/add-a-javascript-popup-to-an-aspnet-button/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tou can use JQuery dialog to this requirement.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 3):

Pop-up windows are a bad idea because they get blocked by pop-up blockers.  You can do something similar, though using [Telerik's controls](http://telerik.com).  The MVC controls are free, not sure about the RAD controls for ASP.Net .

The [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/home) also has a dialog component which will probably do what you want, and it definitely is free.

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you open a popup window within a user click event, the popup will not be blocked. As an example, if you make an async call, when that call completes the popup will be blocked as it did not originate from the user click.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.open` (in javascript) to open a popup but the problem is that almost all modern browsers block popups (*edit based on comment: it doesn't apply when you open a popup while handling a click event, but still:*). My advice: don't create UI with popups. Or use pseudopopups (absolutely positioned divs on top of your page).

Comment: "modern browsers" don't block popups initiated from a user action, so opening one from a click event isn't typically blocked. I prefer them to the current "lightbox" junk because I can move, resize and dismiss them whereas the ones that obscure the page (and generally make me wait while they fade in/out or whatever with some animated effect) are annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="btnpopup" onclick='showpopup();' />

//javascript function
function showpopup(){
    window.open(page url);
}
```

for more information for window.open() 
check it :[window-popup](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: while this answers what the OP was asking it will get killed by pop-up blockers, so your better off using another method to do what you want.